# Python- replace negative numbers shown as a string with parentheses into a float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set with where some of the negative numbers are shown in the format (3.4) and some as -3.4. I am trying to adjust all the parentheses to be float format.

The below formula gives me an error

> replace() argument 1 must be str, not list

```
Total['Rate']=Total['Rate'].apply(lambda x:x.replace(['(',')'],['-','']))

Old Format
(.35)
1.2
-2


Final Format
-.35
1.2
-2
```

Someone suggested
Total['Rate'] = Total['Rate'].apply(lambda x: float(x) if '(' not in x else float('-'+x[x.find("(")+1:x.find(")")]))

This gives the error
TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try:

```
Total['rate'] = Total['rate'].astype(str).str.replace('\((.*)\)', '-\\1')
```

Comment: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Comment: What about `Total['rate'] = Total['rate'].astype(str).str.replace('\((.*)\)', '-\\1')` ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need.

**Demo:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Rate": ["(.35)", "1.2", "-2"]})
print(df["Rate"].str.replace("(", "-").str.rstrip(")").astype(float))
```

**Output:**

```
0   -0.35
1    1.20
2   -2.00
Name: Rate, dtype: float64
```

Comment: i get the error
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Comment: `print(df["Rate"].astype(str).str.replace("(", "-").str.rstrip(")").astype(float))`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [How to use replace method](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/replace)
Just concatenate the `replace()` methods:

```
Total['Rate']=Total['Rate'].apply(lambda x:x.replace('(',')').replace('-',''))
```

Comment: i get the error 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'
i assume its because not all the values are in the () format

Comment: Exactly replace method only applies to string objects.